# webview load custom context menu

Tags: cocoa, webview, contextmenu

I have a `WebView` in a window. In the `WebView`, I am able to restrict it to load its default contextual menu. I need to add a custom contextual menu for the `WebView`. So, please post a sample regarding this. I am new to Mac development. Please help me in this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Assign an object as the web view's `WebUIDelegate` and implement this delegate method:

```
- (NSArray *)webView:(WebView *)sender contextMenuItemsForElement:(NSDictionary *)element defaultMenuItems:(NSArray *)defaultMenuItems
```

You can then return an array of menu items that you want in the contextual menu. You can either add them to the `defaultMenuItems` array or return a new array containing only your items.