# WKWebView disable right click menu

Tags: macos, cocoa, wkwebview

I have `WKWebView` and I want to disable/remove right click menu:

[image]

I found similar issues:

[webview load custom context menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6585075/webview-load-custom-context-menu)

[Cocoa webView - Disable all interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251561/cocoa-webview-disable-all-interaction)

But I cant find

```
optional func webView(_ sender: WebView!,  contextMenuItemsForElement element: [AnyHashable : Any]!, 
     defaultMenuItems: [Any]!) -> [Any]!
```

[method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/webuidelegate/1387728-webview) in `WKUIDelegate` or `WKNavigationDelegate`

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28801032/how-can-the-context-menu-in-wkwebview-on-the-mac-be-modified-or-overridden#28981319

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can the context menu in WKWebView on the Mac be modified or overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28801032/how-can-the-context-menu-in-wkwebview-on-the-mac-be-modified-or-overridden)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figure it out as a most elegant way:

```
- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation {
    [webView evaluateJavaScript:@"document.body.setAttribute('oncontextmenu', 'event.preventDefault();');" completionHandler:nil];
}
```

> Keep in mind that some JavaScripts can override this behaviour

Answer (score 3):

For me nothing from the above worked. I know this is old, but if someone finds this years later like me, here is the solution:

Subclass `WKWebView`, override `buildMenu(with:)` and remove each item that is showing on right click, for me it was `.speech` and `.standardEdit`, so my final code looks like this:

```
import WebKit

class CustomWebView: WKWebView {

    override func buildMenu(with builder: UIMenuBuilder) {
        super.buildMenu(with: builder)
        
        builder.remove(menu: .speech)
        builder.remove(menu: .standardEdit)
    }
    
}
```

Check [this documentation page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uimenu/identifier) for what to remove.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, but not from Swift/Objc side.

Intercept the 'oncontextmenu' event on your html code, for example:

```
<body oncontextmenu='contextMenu(event)'>
```

Then from javascript :

```
function contextMenu(evt)
{
    evt.preventDefault();
}
```

I deduced this from the following post that explain how to customize this menu:

[How can the context menu in WKWebView on the Mac be modified or overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28801032/how-can-the-context-menu-in-wkwebview-on-the-mac-be-modified-or-overridden)

Regards

Answer (score 2):

None of the JavaScript solutions above worked for me as well. @spasbil's answer works great on iOS, but for those of you looking for a solution on macOS, use `willOpenMenu(_:with:)` instead when subclassing `WKWebView`:

```swift
import WebKit

class WebView: WKWebView {
    
    override func willOpenMenu(_ menu: NSMenu, with event: NSEvent) {
        if let reloadMenuItem = menu.item(withTitle: "Reload") {
            menu.removeItem(reloadMenuItem)
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
myWKView.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = false
```

Comment: This is not going to help in disabling the right-click event. This just disables forward and backward touch gestures in the mac/ios application.